# Search Algorithm for tags and contents

Tags: php, mysql, search, tags, full-text-search

i'm designing a tag system and i'm looking for a good search algorithm. It must consider both tags and text contents, maybe with the possibility to give more importance to tag or to contents according to my needs. Is there anything similar in the literature? It's my first time working on such a system, so easy and popular solutions could fit too.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be possible to implement this within MySQL but I think it would be worth looking at dedicated full text search applications for what you're trying to achieve. Most of them handle tags (usually referred to as attributes) as this is a common use case.

I'd recommend looking at the following:

- Sphinx Search
- Elastic Search
- Solr

Comment: you might want to check [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7113008/914705) which includes links to background info and comparisons between some search engines